# Why converting from varchar to varbinary add an interrogation "?" SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, varchar, varbinary

I'm trying to convert this string to `varbinary` in SQL Server:

```
select convert (varbinary(max),'<H2>Un titre</H2><INPUT value="some textre"> <INPUT id=param0 type=hidden value=1031> <INPUT id=exam0 type=hidden value=14711>')
```

it returns this :

```
0x3C48323E556E2074697472653C2F48323E3C494E5055542076616C75653D22736F6D6520746578747265223E203C494E5055542069643D706172616D3020747970653D68696464656E2076616C75653D313033313E203C494E5055542069643D6578616D3020747970653D68696464656E2076616C75653D31343731313E
```

For another reason I want to convert from `varbinary` to `varchar` and I get this result :

```
?<H2>Un titre</H2><INPUT value="some textre"> <INPUT id=param0 type=hidden value=1031> <INPUT id=exam0 type=hidden value=14711>
```

I don't want the "?" in the result.

Why does SQL Server record it with `0x` at the beginning? And how can I avoid that?

Comment: [Where is the `?` you are talking about?](http://rextester.com/XEMU33435)

Comment: at the beginning of the convert result from varbinary to varchar

Comment: Seems like you don't see the results in my commnt

Comment: yes i don't see it

Comment: Hamza there is no `?` as you say in your question.

Comment: The `0x` is behaving as designed, it's the prefix for hexadecimal numbers, and should not be removed. The `?` probably indicates a non-ascii character that's cast to a questionmark when converting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead. Then it will give you the desired output.

```
declare @b varbinary(max)
set @b = 0x3C48323E556E2074697472653C2F48323E3C494E5055542076616C75653D22736F6D6520746578747265223E203C494E5055542069643D706172616D3020747970653D68696464656E2076616C75653D313033313E203C494E5055542069643D6578616D3020747970653D68696464656E2076616C75653D31343731313E
select CAST(@b as varchar(max))
```

or

```
declare @b varbinary(max)
set @b = (select convert (varbinary(max),'<H2>Un titre</H2><INPUT value="some textre"> <INPUT id=param0 type=hidden value=1031> <INPUT id=exam0 type=hidden value=14711>'))
select CAST(@b as varchar(max))
```

**Result**

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to cut off 0x then you need to write like this:

```
declare @d varbinary(max)
declare @c varbinary(max)
set @c = (select convert (varbinary(max),'<H2>Un titre</H2><INPUT value="some textre"> <INPUT id=param0 type=hidden value=1031> <INPUT id=exam0 type=hidden value=14711>'))
select CONVERT(varchar(1000),@c,2)
```